# SQL restore location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, location, restore

I am curious to know if there is a means to determine the location of a file that was used for a restore on a MSSQL Server installation?  I have checked the msdn tables and found no details on the location of the file that was used for the last restore.  I have also checked the log files in the Microsoft SQL Server sub directory log files.  Is there a way to find where this restore was loaded from on a database?

Comment: The information is in msdb. Try `SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory AS rh
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON bs.backup_set_id = rh.backup_set_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset AS bms on bms.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bms.media_set_id`

Comment: This unfortunately is showing me the backup location, not the location from where it was restored.

Comment: The location is that of the backup file the database was restored from.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the script:

```
SELECT
  backupset.database_name,
  restorehistory.destination_database_name,
  restorehistory.restore_date,
  backupmediafamily.physical_device_name
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory restorehistory
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset
    ON restorehistory.backup_set_id = backupset.backup_set_id
  INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily
    ON backupset.media_set_id = backupmediafamily.media_set_id 
ORDER BY restorehistory.restore_date desc
```

This will provide you with the following information:

- **Database Name** - the database that was backed up
- **Destination Database Name** - the database to which the backup was restored
- **Date Restored**
- **Physical Device Name** - file path to the backup used

Comment: Same, only shows me the location where the backup is stored or created to.  I am not finding the location from where the restore came from.

Comment: The resourcehistory.destination_database_name is the database the backup was resotred to. backupset.database_name is the source database of the backup.

Comment: @AmandaC You could add `backupset.server_name` and `backupset.machine_name` to the select list if either of those is what you mean by "location." If you mean the source database, then as Dan mentioned that is `backupset.database_name`

Comment: I've tried everything that has been given and each time it shows me the location where the backup is stored.  I also put the bak file in a directory 2 levels up from its default location and it still registers the same location as the previous time, so the msdb tables are not generating the correct information.  Is there a trigger that needs to be modified to allow for the requested information to generate in the output of the above query?

Comment: @AmandaC The backup history shows where it was restored from, so if you move the backup file location after it has been restored, the history will still show the location where it was located at the time of the restore. If you restore from another file location, there will be another entry in the history of this other location.